# Python - List combinations

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have two lists

```
options = ['+', '-']
protocols = ['SSLV3','TLSV1']
```

I want a new list that looks like 
`['+SSLV3', '-SSLV3', '+TLSV1','-TLSV1']`

I am looking for a one liner solution

Comment: I have tried lambdas and list comprehensions but I only seem to overcomplicate things

Comment: For a small number of short lists, using nested for loops, as in the two answers below, is fine. Otherwise, use `itertools.product `, which returns a generator that you can iterate over or convert to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include more than one for loop in a list comprehension.

`[option + protocol for protocol in protocols for option in options]`

Comment: `product` could also be used: `[y+x for x,y in itertools.product(protocols, options)]`, but for small lists the performance is about the same.

Answer (score 2):

For small enough N, two simple loops will suffice:

```
$ python
>>> for protocol in ['SSLV3', 'TLSV1']:
...     for option in ['+','-']:
...         print(option + protocol)
... 
+SSLV3
-SSLV3
+TLSV1
-TLSV1
```